# I am developing new module in orangehrm

Tags: php, symfony, orangehrm

I'll add all credentials in modules,screen and menus tables and added new plugin folder in symfony plugins. but after call this plugin it displaying me  "Internal Error Occurred".
my plugin folder in symfony

[plugin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20pO3.png)

how i can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing cache folder inside ***project/symfony***.

Go To Command Line Interface > **cd your_project_folder_path/symfony** > 
    **php symfony cc**